# "Input type=text" tab indexing issue in phonegap .apk

Tags: android, cordova

I am using https://build.phonegap.com to create phonegap .apk file. 
After opening .apk file I have got a very peculiar bug regarding tabindexing. Tab button of soft keybord is not shifting cursor to next textbox **from a textbox**.

Tabbing is working fine from input[type=tel] but not from input[type=text], input[type=email] and input[type=search].

**Device used is Iball slide 3G Q1035 tablet and android version is 4.2.2.**

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <span><input id='test1' tabindex='1' name='test1' type='text'></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><input id='test2' tabindex='2' name='test2' type='text'></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><input id='test3' tabindex='3' name='test3' type='search'></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><input id='test4' tabindex='4' name='test4' type='url'></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><input id='test5' tabindex='5' name='test5' type='email'></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span><input id='test6' tabindex='6' name='test6' type='tel'></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

INDEX.JS

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Also what specific devices have you tested on?

Comment: I have shared HTML, javascript and device above. I haven't made any changes in cordova.js.

Comment: I confirm the bug, I'm having the same problem on a nexus with android 5

Comment: I am having the same issue in IOS 9